# Set size of a div within a container, when the other div in the same container has undefined height

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a container for my landing page.

In the middle column, I have a nagivation bar div, and below it the "content" div.

The content div can have several content box divs, which makes the content div an unpredictable size.

Currently, the navigation bar won't change size with it having value flex: 2 and the content div having flex: 8. It doesn't matter what flex values I give them, the navigation bar is still extremely thin and the content div massive.

I assume this is because the content box div's are expanding the content div, but I'm not sure how to go about establishing a set size for my navigation bar.

Here's the code for reference:

```
<div className='container'>
  <div className='middleCol'>
    <div className='navigationBar'>
      <div className='navCol' id='logo'>Logo Placeholder</div>
      <div className='navCol' id='options'>
        <div className='navOptions'>
          Sign in
        </div>
        <div className='navOptions'>
          Register
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className='content'>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='sideCol'/>
  <style jsx>
    {`
    .container{
      width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      ${debug && 'border: 1px solid black;'}
    }
    .middleCol{
      flex: 7;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      ${debug && 'border: 1px solid black;'}
    }
    .navigationBar{
      flex: 2;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      background: ${colours.PRIMARYBLUE};
      ${debug && 'border: 1px solid black;'}
    }
    .content{
      flex: 8;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }`}
  </style>
</div>
```

And for reference, here's the "content box" divs that go inside the content div:

```
<LandingLayout>
  <div className='contentBox' id='box1'>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
  <div className='contentBox' id='box2'>
    <h1>Other content</h1>
  </div>
  <style jsx>{`
    .contentBox {
      padding-top: 20%;
      padding-bottom: 20%;
      background: white;
      flex: 1;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #box1 {
      background: ${colours.PRIMARYBLUE};
    }

    #box2 {
      background: white;
    }

  `}</style>
</LandingLayout>
```

Comment: Can you link to sandbox demoing your issue? The code you've provided makes it difficult to reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: try removing `flex: 7;` from `.middleCol`

Comment: check this website: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/